# Show/hide div only one at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This code is the untouched version of a FAQ consisting of three answers that can be shown or hidden when click on it. My task is to modify to show only one answer at a time (the other two must close).
I got a hint to use a for loop to go through the h2 elements in the array and remove the class attribute for all h2 elements that aren’t the one that has been clicked. 
Thank you,

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

// the event handler for the click event of each h2 element

var toggle = function() {
    var h2 = this;                    // clicked h2 tag     
    var div = h2.nextElementSibling;  // h2 tag's sibling div tag




    // toggle plus and minus image in h2 elements by adding or removing a class
    if (h2.hasAttribute("class")) { 
        h2.removeAttribute("class");    
    } else { 
        h2.setAttribute("class", "minus"); 
    }

    // toggle div visibility by adding or removing a class
    if (div.hasAttribute("class")) { 
        div.removeAttribute("class");
    } else { 
        div.setAttribute("class", "open"); 
    } 
};

window.onload = function() {
    // get the h2 tags
    var faqs = $("faqs");
    var h2Elements = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2");

    // attach event handler for each h2 tag     
    for (var i = 0; i < h2Elements.length; i++ ) {
        h2Elements[i].onclick = toggle;
    }


    // set focus on first h2 tag's <a> tag
    h2Elements[0].firstChild.focus();       
};
```

Comment: Design first, code second! In the design you need to consider things like does  clicking on a link in the h2 element navigates to another page, what to do if user clicks on an answer that is already open, do you need to process more than two h2 elements, and if so, why isn't the click handler  inside the `onload` function where it can access the collection of h2 elements. Good luck with the homework :)

Comment: Thank you :) I ll make sure to write pseudocode out before coding))

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might do the trick assuming your existing script/markup is currently working. I can't test my answer without the HTML/CSS.

Essentially it just iterates over the faq items when ones clicked and hides them if they aren't the element that was clicked or shows if it is the element clicked - it won't toggle if the same element is clicked twice - one will always remain open.

```js
"use strict";
    var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

    // the event handler for the click event of each h2 element

    window.onload = function() {
        // get the h2 tags
        var faqs = $("faqs");
        var h2Elements = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2");
      
        function accordionClick(){
           var h2;
           for(var i=0; i < h2Elements.length; i++){
             h2 = h2Elements[i]; 
             if(h2 == this){ // The item we clicked
               if(!h2.hasAttribute("class")){ // If it's open
                 closeItem(h2);
               } else{ // If not 
                 openItem(h2); 
               }
             } else{ // Not the item we clicked so it should be closed
               closeItem(h2);
             }
           }
        }
      
        function openItem(h2){
            var div = h2.nextElementSibling;
            h2.removeAttribute("class")
            div.setAttribute("class", "open");
        }
      
        function closeItem(h2){
            var div = h2.nextElementSibling;
            h2.setAttribute("class", "minus")
            div.removeAttribute("class");
        }
      
        // attach event handler for each h2 tag and init classes     
        for (var i = 0; i < h2Elements.length; i++ ) {
            h2Elements[i].onclick = accordionClick;
            closeItem(h2Elements[i]);
        }

        // set focus on first h2 tag's <a> tag
        h2Elements[0].firstChild.focus();       
    };
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 15px 25px;
}
h1 { 
    font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(images/plus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
h2.minus {
    background: url(images/minus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
a:focus, a:hover { 
    color: blue; 
}
div {
    display: none;
}
div.open {
    display: block;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
p {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<main id="faqs">
        <h1>JavaScript FAQs</h1>
        <h2><a href="#" >What is JavaScript?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>JavaScript is a programming language that's built into the major web browsers.
                It makes web pages more responsive and saves round trips to the server.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="#">What is jQuery?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>jQuery is a library of the JavaScript functions that you're most likely 
               to need as you develop web sites.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="#">Why is jQuery becoming so popular?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>Three reasons:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>It's free.</li>
                <li>It lets you get more done in less time.</li>
                <li>All of its functions are cross-browser compatible.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have used a live snippet - it will produce an error as none of the DOM elements exist which means `h2Elements` and `faqs` won't return anything useful and `faq.getElementswByTagName()` will fail. If you can please provide the  HTML and CSS for your script I'll update the answer so that it's functional

Comment: Thank you Brian! I will post HTML and CSS for the script now. Sorry for a late reply.

Comment: @Pappricot you're welcome, I've updated my example with your HTML and CSS and it seems to function as I expected :). Let me know if there's any other issues and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Brian!:) It ran perfectly!  Although I'm still trying to figure if there is a way to combine the toggle function and show one/hide all function. I'll design my code the way you do in the future, my original code design was  confusing even to me :))

Comment: No worries, breaking out the open/close functions into their own functions keeps things neater, then adding a conditional to the currently clicked item to test if it's open or not allows us to close it if it's already open :). It's good to organise your code into small functional blocks - if you see  how I refactored from last revision to this - it was pretty much a copy + paste to move code from the `if` to the `function` :).

Answer (score 0):

HTML for the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FAQs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="faqs.js"></script>     
</head>

<body>
    <main id="faqs">
        <h1>JavaScript FAQs</h1>
        <h2><a href="#" >What is JavaScript?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>JavaScript is a programming language that's built into the major web browsers.
                It makes web pages more responsive and saves round trips to the server.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="#">What is jQuery?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>jQuery is a library of the JavaScript functions that you're most likely 
               to need as you develop web sites.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="#">Why is jQuery becoming so popular?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>Three reasons:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>It's free.</li>
                <li>It lets you get more done in less time.</li>
                <li>All of its functions are cross-browser compatible.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS for the script:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 15px 25px;
}
h1 { 
    font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(images/plus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
h2.minus {
    background: url(images/minus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
a:focus, a:hover { 
    color: blue; 
}
div {
    display: none;
}
div.open {
    display: block;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
p {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```